# Spark UI - History Server - Unable to view driver logs

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, azure-aks, spark-ui

I have deployed "Spark History Server" in Azure Kubernetes Services(AKS) using Helm chart.

Then I submitted a SparkApplication(SparkOperatorOnk8s) with the below yaml

```
apiVersion: sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  type: Python
  pythonVersion: '3'
  mode: cluster
  image: 'docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.5.0'
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: 'local:///opt/spark/work-dir/script.py'
  sparkVersion: 3.5.0
  restartPolicy:
    type: OnFailure
    onFailureRetries: 3
    onFailureRetryInterval: 10
    onSubmissionFailureRetries: 5
    onSubmissionFailureRetryInterval: 20
  volumes:
    - name: spark-script-volume
      configMap:
        name: hello-world-cm
    - name: code-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: code-volume
  sparkConf:
    "spark.eventLog.enabled": "true"
    "spark.eventLog.dir": "file:/data"     
    "spark.ui.threadDumpsEnabled": "true"
    "spark.history.fs.logDirectory": "file:/data"
    "spark.driver.log.persistToDfs.enabled": "true"
    "spark.driver.log.dfsDir": "file:/data" 
    "spark.history.fs.driverlog.cleaner.enabled": "true"
    "spark.history.fs.driverlog.cleaner.interval": "1d"
    "spark.history.fs.driverlog.cleaner.maxAge": "5d"
    "spark.io.compression.codec": "snappy"
  driver:
    tolerations:
    - key: "kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "spot"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
    volumeMounts:
      - name: spark-script-volume
        mountPath: /opt/spark/work-dir/script.py
        subPath: hello_world.py
      - mountPath: /data
        name: code-volume              
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "2"
    memory: 512m
    labels:
      version: 3.5.0
    serviceAccount: my-release-spark
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0  # Set the user ID to 0 (root)    
  executor:
    tolerations:
    - key: "kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "spot"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /data
        name: code-volume          
    cores: 1
    instances: 1
    memory: 512m
    labels:
      version: 3.5.0
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0  # Set the user ID to 0 (root)
```

The Spark driver pods have completed fine and I can see the driver logs using `kubectl logs hello-world-driver` . Also, I can view the driver logs in the attached PVC

```
root@my-spark-history-server-75659fc5b5-wn2wh:/data# ls -lrta
total 1644
drwx------ 2 root root  16384 Nov 20 01:51 lost+found
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 108320 Nov 20 05:43 local-1700458995725
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 108320 Nov 20 14:50 local-1700491856943
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 108357 Nov 20 14:54 local-1700492094743
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 113695 Nov 20 17:24 local-1700501079419
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 113695 Nov 23 08:51 local-1700729506218
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Nov 29 11:12 ..
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 113691 Nov 29 15:46 local-1701272771644
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 113691 Nov 29 16:18 local-1701274722700
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 110842 Nov 29 17:56 local-1701280583084
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 110878 Nov 29 18:08 local-1701281298745
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 113695 Nov 29 18:19 local-1701281994847
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root    100 Nov 29 18:20 .local-1701282050932_driver.log.crc
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  11550 Nov 29 18:20 local-1701282050932_driver.log
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 110968 Nov 29 18:20 local-1701282050932
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root    100 Nov 29 18:39 .local-1701283172349_driver.log.crc
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  11550 Nov 29 18:39 local-1701283172349_driver.log
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 111169 Nov 29 18:39 local-1701283172349
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root    100 Nov 29 18:50 .local-1701283854944_driver.log.crc
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  11550 Nov 29 18:50 local-1701283854944_driver.log
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 111129 Nov 29 18:50 local-1701283854944
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root    100 Nov 29 19:02 .local-1701284518591_driver.log.crc
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  11548 Nov 29 19:02 local-1701284518591_driver.log
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Nov 29 19:02 .
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 111159 Nov 29 19:02 local-1701284518591
```

However, I couldn't see the driver and executor logs in the Spark History Server UI

**Spark History Server:**
[image]
[image]

Spark History Server k8s pod logs:

```
23/11/29 19:07:14 INFO FsHistoryProvider: Parsing
file:/data/local-1701283172349_driver.log for listing data... 23/11/29
19:07:14 ERROR FsHistoryProvider: Exception while merging application
listings org.apache.spark.SparkIllegalArgumentException:
[CODEC_NOT_AVAILABLE] The codec log is not available. Consider to set
the config "spark.io.compression.codec" to "snappy".
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.$anonfun$createCodec$2(CompressionCodec.scala:92)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileReader$.$anonfun$openEventLog$2(EventLogFileReaders.scala:142)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileReader$.$anonfun$openEventLog$1(EventLogFileReaders.scala:142)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileReader$.openEventLog(EventLogFileReaders.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$2(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1138)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithResource(SparkErrorUtils.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithResource$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$1(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1138)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$parseAppEventLogs$1$adapted(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1136)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.parseAppEventLogs(FsHistoryProvider.scala:1136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.doMergeApplicationListingInternal(FsHistoryProvider.scala:796)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.doMergeApplicationListing(FsHistoryProvider.scala:765)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.mergeApplicationListing(FsHistoryProvider.scala:714)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider.$anonfun$checkForLogs$18(FsHistoryProvider.scala:581)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The error message suggests that there is an issue with the codec used for log compression in the Spark History Server. Did you make the change it is suggesting you to do in the error-org.apache.spark.SparkIllegalArgumentException: [CODEC_NOT_AVAILABLE] The codec log is not available. Consider setting the config "spark.io.compression.codec" to "snappy".

Comment: yes. I have set "spark.io.compression.codec": "snappy" in the spark conf. Still unable to view the driver logs